# html5 boilerplate: how to add third-party js?

Tags: javascript, html, html5boilerplate

I am not a web developer, and though I believe this question must have a simple answer, I couldn't find it in the documentation, nor online.

I'll use html5 boilerplate to create a very simple app.

I would like to run

```
npm install an-arbitrary-js-library --save
gulp build
```

and be able to

```
import a_random_function from 'an-arbitrary-js-library'
```

in my js/main.js file.

How can I adapt my HTML5 Boilerplate to add third-party JS libraries to my project automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Just put a script tag with the source referring to your library in the index.html file.
I don't know how you orginzed the project but you can copy the file of your third library from node_module to the project `js/vendor` or any other folders using gulp see from line 69 --> 95 [here](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/5.3.0/gulpfile.js), this is the way they set jQuery in the project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Copying the file and inserting a script tag is a valid solution, but it isn't automatic. Just as I can npm install * --save, and have npm edit my package.json, I'd like to know if there is something I can do so that my gulp file gets edited automatically too, or similar.

Comment: I don't think you can update the gulp file automatically because the gulp file is the one who automate the building process, so you need to write it yourself in the gulp process.